# how to make non ssl request to an external webapi from ssl running website

Tags: http, ssl, https, weather-api

I am making requests to get weather info from [geonames](http://geonames.org) and [openweather](http://openweathermap.org/) but the problem is I also m using GeoLocation Api to get user location and that needs https. Now When I make http request it says

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xyz/dashboard' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat=33.6154812&lng=73.0105414&username=xyz'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

What is the solution to make this `http` request while I am on `https`.

Comment: Are you making the request from client side?

Comment: Yes from a browser client.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider perform the request server side and send the data to the client through your secure server.